# how to hide an image over patches in netlogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have imported an image over patches by using netlogo command "import-pcolors "abc.png" ".

Now i am trying to hide an image so that turtles interact with the hidden image as only by following those patches of the hidden image.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by hide the image?

Comment: actually i want to know that can we hide image that is imported in our model in netlogo. or we can say that can we hide patches over which image is imported by using "import-pcolors" command as like we can hide turtles in netlogo.

Answer (score 2):

first make an extra patch variable for storing the color information:

```
patches-own [invisible-pcolor]
```

(calling it whatever you want)

then after `import-pcolors` do:

```
ask patches [
  set invisible-pcolor pcolor
  set pcolor black
]
```

and then have your turtles interact with `invisible-pcolor` instead of `pcolor`.

another solution would be to fill the drawing layer with black (or any color), e.g. by making a giant turtle of the color you want and having it do `stamp` then `die`